# -moz-box-flex is not flexing? Works with (Chrome/Webkit)

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I have been looking for the past 8 hours or so trying to find what I possibly missed in HTML/CSS code, yet Firefox will not flex my page content?  It works in Chrome (I've been making sure for each -webkit-box-flex there is the -moz-box-flex vice a versa).  Is there something I'm missing?  Your time and help is greatly appreciated!

```
*
    {margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

body
    {width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    background-color: #696969;
    background-image: url(squairy_light.png);
    background-repeat: ;
    background-position:;
    }

header, footer, article, nav, section, hgroup, aside
    {display: block;
    }

#banner
    {display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

#fullpage_box
    {max-width: 1000px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    }

#page_box
    {display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    }

#content_box
    {-webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horisontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I found the fix/problem.

the

```
> display: -moz-box;
> display: -webkit-box;
```

should be ONLY be in the parent folder (In this case only the #page_box not both"). Well in my case, that is what worked. Anyhow, the css displayed is in ascending order of parent > child. The code below is corrected from the code above. Hope this helps someone. Drove me nuts.

```
  #fullpage_box
    {max-width: 1000px;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    }

#page_box
    {display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    }

#content_box
    {-webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content_box
{-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-orient: **horisontal**; <------------
box-orient: horizontal;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}
```

THAT was probably your mistake ;)