# Webkit-flex working while moz-flex is not

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have this CSS on a webpage, and when I test it in chrome and webkit-box-flex does exactly what it's meant to.

However, on firefox, it doesn't.

Please can someone look at my CSS and tell me what I need to change in order for this to work on both?

```
.buttonGroup
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack:justify;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.buttonGroup > li
{
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;


    border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;

    background: rgb(243,243,243); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,243,1) 0%, rgba(194,194,194,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(243,243,243,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(194,194,194,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,243,1) 0%,rgba(194,194,194,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,243,1) 0%,rgba(194,194,194,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,243,1) 0%,rgba(194,194,194,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(243,243,243,1) 0%,rgba(194,194,194,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f3', endColorstr='#c2c2c2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: #6b6b6b;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6pc7wvt/

I have looked at [-moz-box-flex is not flexing? Works with (Chrome/Webkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343156/moz-box-flex-is-not-flexing-works-with-chrome-webkit)

but his fix doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the old prefixes and syntax. Firefox now supports flexbox natively without prefixes.

The current syntax would be:

```
.buttonGroup {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.buttonGroup > li {
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
    flex:1;
}
```

```js
$("ul.buttonGroup").click(function (event) {
    $("li", this)
        .removeClass("selected")
        .filter(event.target)
        .addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.buttonGroup {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.buttonGroup > li {
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
    flex:1;
    
    border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(243, 243, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 194, 194, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f3f3f3', endColorstr='#c2c2c2', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    color: #6b6b6b;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.buttonGroup > li:first-child {
    border-left: solid 1px #9a9a99;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.buttonGroup > li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.buttonGroup > li.selected {
    background: rgb(25, 58, 127);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1) 5%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1)), color-stop(5%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1) 5%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1) 5%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1) 5%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(25, 58, 127, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 86, 178, 1) 5%, rgba(97, 150, 241, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#193a7f', endColorstr='#6196f1', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #193a7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="buttonGroup">
    <li class="selected">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6pc7wvt/3/)

You might want to start using a prefixing tool like [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) or [**Prefix Free**](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/). They take all the hard work out of it.